# Split characters by colon in several columns in R

Tags: r, strsplit

I have some data which I have already split them by colons. I want to split all the contents of each column by colon.

Here is an example of my data:

```
                      V8                        V9                      V10
1 0/0:0,108,255:36:0:0:99  0/0:0,255,255:103:0:0:99 0/0:0,226,255:107:3:0:99
2 1/1:255,69,0:23:23:0:65  1/1:255,159,0:63:62:0:99 0/1:255,0,255:58:25:4:99
```

and I want them to look like:

```
                      V8                        V9                      V10
1 0/0 0,108,255 36 0 0 99  0/0 0,255,255 103 0 0 99 0/0 0,226,255 107 3 0 99
2 1/1 255,69,0 23 23 0 65  1/1 255,159,0 63 62 0 99 0/1 255,0,255 58 25 4 99
```

Comment: It is not clear what do you want to have in each cell? a character or an atomic vector?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data.frame is called SODF, use `gsub`. `lapply` will let you apply the function to all the columns in your `data.frame` (since a `data.frame` is a special kind of `list` in R):

```
> data.frame(lapply(SODF, function(x) gsub(":", " ", x)))
                       V8                       V9                      V10
1 0/0 0,108,255 36 0 0 99 0/0 0,255,255 103 0 0 99 0/0 0,226,255 107 3 0 99
2 1/1 255,69,0 23 23 0 65 1/1 255,159,0 63 62 0 99 0/1 255,0,255 58 25 4 99
```